# Mui MenuItem doesn't follow select width

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, sx

The issue that I am having is that mui element select when clicked the menu items don't match the screen size after some screen resizing by the user.
I have subscribed to the resize event and managed to calculate the select width and pass it to the menu props like this:

```
<Select
      id="somecss"
      className="anothercss__options"
      variant="outlined"
      displayEmpty
      placeholder={
        <span className="Someothercss">{placeholderVal}</span>
      }
      ref={selectRef}
      onOpen={() => {
        calculateInitialWidth(selectRef.current);
      }}
      MenuProps={{
        slotProps: {
          paper: {
            sx: {
              minWidth: 'unset',
              width: menuWidth,
            },
          },
        },
      }}
      value={selectedThingId || ''}
      onChange={onSelectThing}
    >
```

The fix works and the menu items now match the select element, but here is the catch, if I switch to dark theme, the menu items will not respect the dark theme and the colors will not adjust.

How can I only target the width of those elements?

Note: min-width is also added, because strangely enough, mui calculates the min width based on the initial screen size you have when the components mount, so when you resize, you guessed it, it will not go below the min width this applies only for the menu items,not the select parent.